# 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables :

1) users

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->string('id')->unique();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('telephone')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

2) users_games

```
  Schema::create('user_games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->boolean('state')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Every user can have many `games` so i want every `game->user_id` to match with the user's id.

I have the below function where i create a user :

```
 public function createNewUser(){

        // Check here if user is about to win,

        $mUniqueID = uniqid("",true); // create an id
        $user = new User();
        $user->id = $mUniqueID;
        $saved = $user->save();


        $user = User::find($mUniqueID);
        $currentGame = new UserGame(['state' => false]); // It is in 'fillable' array - boolean
        $user->games()->save($currentGame);

        $mUserInformation = [
            'mUniqueID' => $mUniqueID,
            'game_id'   => $user->games()->latest()->first(),
        ];

        if($saved)
            return $mUserInformation;
        else
            return redirect()->route('game');
    }
```

The error i get :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_name`.`user_games`, CONSTRAINT `user_games_user_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   (SQL: insert into `user_games` (`state`, `user_id`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (0, 59380, 2017-06-07 14:18:52, 2017-06-07
>   14:18:52))

I can't understand why this error occurs. If you need any more information please ask and i will provide.

**EDIT 1 :**

Also, in my database an id of user is : `59380b495c1942.30562655` but the error mentions only `59380`, shouldn't it be `59380b495c1942.30562655` ?

**EDIT 2:**

> User.php model

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
// all fillables here
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

        public function games()
        {

            return $this->hasMany('App\UserGame');
        }

    }
```

> UserGame.php model

```
class UserGame extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'state'
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Antonis Tsimourtos add model plz

Comment: @Akram updated question

Comment: edit    $table->string('id')->unique(); to    $table->text('id')->unique();

Comment: @Akram i changed `string` to `text` on both tables and i got this error `1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length` . I think i can't set primary key a `text` type in MySQL

Comment: ok go to  /config/database.php and change 'engine' => null, to 'engine' => 'InnoDB',and use   $table->increments('id');

Comment: @Akram well it worked using integers but i wanted to have random strings..

Comment: so add "composer require webpatser/laravel-uuid" https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid and when install and add provider change increments to uuid

Comment: add this public $incrementing = false; in models

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use InnoDB engine in  /config/database.php change  'engine' => null, to 'engine' => 'InnoDB'

To use uuid you can add laravel-uuid by add `composer require webpatser/laravel-uuid`, after add the aliases in config/app.php

Change Migrations `$table->increments('id')` to `$table->uuid('id')` and add `$table->primary('id')`

In models add public `$incrementing = false;` Hope help you

In the end add trait

```
namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
trait Uuids
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });
    }
}
```

In model also add u`se Uuids`;